# MySQL Not In Not Working

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, notin

I am working on putting a MySQL statement together and am wondering what the problem is with it.
Why doesn't this MySQL statement work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `deals` 
WHERE CATEGORY NOT 
IN  'Construction & Repair'
AND (
EXPIRE_DATE >= NOW() 
OR EXPIRE_DATE IS NULL
)
AND LOCATION =  'Melbourne'
AND STATUS =  'Active'
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

I get the following error message:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Construction & Repair' AND ( EXPIRE_DATE >= NOW( ) OR EXPIRE_DATE IS NULL ) AND' at line 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in brackets

```
WHERE CATEGORY NOT 
IN  ('Construction & Repair')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong, you want it to be:

```
 NOT IN ("item1", "item2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `deals` 
WHERE CATEGORY = 'Construction & Repair'
AND (
EXPIRE_DATE >= NOW() 
OR EXPIRE_DATE IS NULL
)
AND LOCATION =  'Melbourne'
AND STATUS =  'Active'
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

anything after IN should be in parentheses.

```
IN('Construction & Repair')
```